# Javascript inheritance, member undefined

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I'm making a "class" in a file called Animation.js:

```
function Animation(s) {
  this.span = s;
};

Animation.prototype = Object.create(Animation.prototype);
Animation.prototype.constructor = Animation;
```

And I create a child class which is in a file called LinearAnimation.js:

```
function LinearAnimation(s, cP) {
     Animation.call(s);
     this.controlPoints = cP;
};

LinearAnimation.prototype = Object.create(Animation.prototype);
LinearAnimation.prototype.constructor = LinearAnimation;
```

The problem is, when I access to `this.span` member in the LinearAnimation class it says it's `undefined`. Am I implementing this well? Thank you.

Comment: At a glance, you probably want `Animation.call(this, s)`, not `Animation.call(s)`. The first argument to `call` sets `this` for the function invocation.

Comment: `Animation.prototype = Object.create(Animation.prototype);` is probably not what you wanted either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) function takes a *thisArg* as it's first argument, meant to be the `this` inside the called function. After that, any other argument(s) is(are..) passed as input to the called function.

Also, there's no point in replacing the prototype of a function (class) with an object inherited from itself.

Try this:

```js
function Animation(s) {
  this.span = s;
};

function LinearAnimation(s, cP) {
     Animation.call(this, s);
     this.controlPoints = cP;
};
LinearAnimation.prototype = Object.create(Animation.prototype);
LinearAnimation.prototype.constructor = LinearAnimation;

var la = new LinearAnimation('something', [1, 2, 3]);

console.log(la);
```

Answer (score 2):

You want `Animation.call(this, s)`, not `Animation.call(s)`. The first argument to `call` sets `this` for the function invocation. In your code, you're calling `Animation` with a `this` of `s`, so your `s` argument gets a `span` property, rather than the `this` being constructed in `LinearAniamtion`.